# Convert IEnumerable<dynamic> to DataTable

Tags: c#

I query to Database to get data. It might has more than 1 row. I save them into IEnumerable.

Why dynamic? because I might add new column in the table and I dont want to change my code to adapt it again.

Then, I convert the IEnumerable to datatable. I have a problem to get the properties inside the dynamic object. Anyone can help me?

Here is my code:

```
DataTable dt;
string query = "SELECT * FROM WORKSHOP WHERE WORKSHOPID = 1";

// Execute Query
var result = Execute(query);

// Convert IEnumerable<dynamic> to DataTable (I Have Problem Here)
dt = CsvConverter.EnumToDataTable(result);

// Convert DataTable To CSV
var csv = CsvConverter.DataTableToCsv(dt, ",", true);

// Save File
string fileName = Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".csv";
File.AppendAllText(fileName, csv);

// Method to Execute Query
public IEnumerable<dynamic> Execute(string commandText)
{
   using (var result = databaseManager.ReadData(commandText, false))
      foreach (IDataRecord record in result)
      {
         yield return new DataRecordDynamicWrapper(record);
      }
}

// Wrapper of Dynamic Record
public class DataRecordDynamicWrapper : DynamicObject
{
    private IDataRecord _dataRecord;
    public DataRecordDynamicWrapper(IDataRecord dataRecord) { _dataRecord = dataRecord; }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        result = _dataRecord[binder.Name];
        return result != null;
    }
}

// Method to Convert Enum to DT
public static DataTable EnumToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> l_oItems)
    {
        DataTable oReturn = new DataTable(typeof (T).Name);
        object[] a_oValues;
        int i;

        //#### Collect the a_oProperties for the passed T
        PropertyInfo[] a_oProperties = typeof (T).GetType().GetProperties();


        //#### Traverse each oProperty, .Add'ing each .Name/.BaseType into our oReturn value
        //####     NOTE: The call to .BaseType is required as DataTables/DataSets do not support nullable types, so it's non-nullable counterpart Type is required in the .Column definition
        foreach (PropertyInfo oProperty in a_oProperties)
        {
            oReturn.Columns.Add(oProperty.Name, BaseType(oProperty.PropertyType));
        }

        //#### Traverse the l_oItems
        foreach (T oItem in l_oItems)
        {
            //#### Collect the a_oValues for this loop
            a_oValues = new object[a_oProperties.Length];

            //#### Traverse the a_oProperties, populating each a_oValues as we go
            for (i = 0; i < a_oProperties.Length; i++)
            {
                a_oValues[i] = a_oProperties[i].GetValue(oItem, null);
            }

            //#### .Add the .Row that represents the current a_oValues into our oReturn value
            oReturn.Rows.Add(a_oValues);
        }

        //#### Return the above determined oReturn value to the caller
        return oReturn;
    }

    public static Type BaseType(Type oType)
    {
        //#### If the passed oType is valid, .IsValueType and is logicially nullable, .Get(its)UnderlyingType
        if (oType != null && oType.IsValueType &&
            oType.IsGenericType && oType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (Nullable<>)
            )
        {
            return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(oType);
        }
            //#### Else the passed oType was null or was not logicially nullable, so simply return the passed oType
        else
        {
            return oType;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which problem? Your array `a_oProperties` is empty?

Comment: @AlbertoSolano Ya, it is empty... But I have something in l_oItems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use the reflection APIs enumerate the dynamically bound members of a `DynamicObject`.  You can only bind to them on demand, by name.  Your code, as written, will only return the properties defined on the actual `DynamicObject` class, which defines no properties (hence the empty array).

As an alternative to using reflection, you could have your `DataRecordDynamicWrapper` implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor`, which gives you a way to expose the properties on your data record ([complete example here](https://gist.github.com/mstrobel/8541557)):

```
public class DataRecordDynamicWrapper : DynamicObject, ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    private IDataRecord _dataRecord;
    private PropertyDescriptorCollection _properties;

    //
    // (existing members)
    //

    PropertyDescriptorCollection ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
    {
        if (_properties == null)
            _properties = GenerateProperties();
        return _properties;
    }

    private PropertyDescriptorCollection GenerateProperties()
    {
        var count = _dataRecord.FieldCount;
        var properties = new PropertyDescriptor[count];

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            properties[i] = new DataRecordProperty(
                i,
                _dataRecord.GetName(i),
                _dataRecord.GetFieldType(i));
        }

        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties);
    }

    //
    // (implement other ICustomTypeDescriptor members...)
    //

    private sealed class DataRecordProperty : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        private static readonly Attribute[] NoAttributes = new Attribute[0];

        private readonly int _ordinal;
        private readonly Type _type;

        public DataRecordProperty(int ordinal, string name, Type type)
            : base(name, NoAttributes)
        {
            _ordinal = ordinal;
            _type = type;
        }

        public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            var wrapper = ((DataRecordDynamicWrapper)component);
            return wrapper._dataRecord.GetValue(_ordinal);
        }

        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }

        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override Type ComponentType
        {
            get { return typeof(IDataRecord); }
        }

        public override bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public override Type PropertyType
        {
            get { return _type; }
        }
    }
}
```

You could then modify your `EnumToDataTable()` method to use the `System.ComponenetModel` APIs instead of `System.Reflection`:

```
public static DataTable EnumToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> l_oItems)
{
    var firstItem = l_oItems.FirstOrDefault();
    if (firstItem == null)
        return new DataTable();

    DataTable oReturn = new DataTable(TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(firstItem));
    object[] a_oValues;
    int i;

    var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(firstItem);

    foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
    {
        oReturn.Columns.Add(property.Name, BaseType(property.PropertyType));
    }

    //#### Traverse the l_oItems
    foreach (T oItem in l_oItems)
    {
        //#### Collect the a_oValues for this loop
        a_oValues = new object[properties.Count];

        //#### Traverse the a_oProperties, populating each a_oValues as we go
        for (i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
            a_oValues[i] = properties[i].GetValue(oItem);

        //#### .Add the .Row that represents the current a_oValues into our oReturn value
        oReturn.Rows.Add(a_oValues);
    }

    //#### Return the above determined oReturn value to the caller
    return oReturn;
}
```

The upside to this approach is that `EnumToDataTable()` will fall back to the standard type descriptor for items which do not implement `ICustomTypeDescriptor` (e.g., for a plain old CLR object, it will behave similarly to your original code).

Comment: Wao, a really good explanation and answer. You deserved a point from me :)

Answer (score 0):

The array `a_oProperties` is empty, because you don't have any public property declared in the class `DataRecordDynamicWrapper`. Indeed, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#fbid=ycqo-G3QGuN?United%20States%20%28English%29), the `GetProperties()` method returns all the public properties of the current Type.

The only possible candidate as property could be:

```
public DataRecordDynamicWrapper(IDataRecord dataRecord) { _dataRecord = dataRecord; }
```

but it is a method. Moreover, the method/property name is missing.

A property, in your case, should be declared like this:

```
private IDataRecord _dataRecord;

public IDataRecord DataRecord 
{ 
  set{
     _dataRecord = value; 
  }
  get{
     return _dataRecord;
  }
}
```

More info about properties [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx).